# Add filter behaviour to json_encode()

Tags: php

I have an array that I encode to JSON for a API I'm building, the array is coming from a database and contains some data that I don't want in the JSON response. So what I could do of course is just iterate through the array, modify it and then pass the modified array to `json_encode()`. But as json_encode() itself iterate through it I was thinking that I could increase performance and maybe even readability if I could just somehow tell `json_encode` to filter away certain keys while It is generating the JSON.

It seems like `json_encode` does not make this possible, but maybe there is something else I can use to encode to json that will? I saw that json_encode() has a option parameter which can change behaviour but you can't seem to add your own?

For example, I recall I once skimmed through a json parser class and it had a method called something like `parseKey($key, $val)` which you could just override if you wanted to add, lets say, a filter.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
$data = array("foo"=>1, "bar"=>2, "baz"=>3);
$rmk = array("foo");
$json = json_encode(array_diff_key($data, array_flip($rmk)));
```

That will filter out the values with keys in `$rmk`. However when it comes to increased readability I'm not sure.

Comment: Well that is still passing a modified array, I wanna modify it while it encodes. For a small array like this It's fine but imagine having a big array, I have to run two long iterations (one by my self and one performed by the encoding).

Comment: That is very true, however since this is using `standard` functions I sure hope it's quicker than writing some sort of own filtering function. It sounds like you want to `stream` the array into  `json_encode` whilst checking the keys, that would be very, very interesting. :D

Comment: Indeed! I was thinking about some sort of hook but mentioning streaming got me thinking. I know you can create objects acting like arrays in php by subclassing ArrayObject. Wouldn't it be possible to do that and then put the filtering or whatever you wanna do there. Then json_encode will ask that object for the values and you will only iterate inside json_encode :)

Comment: I do think it is possible, but I'm not sure you'll get any performance-gains from this. The algorithm for checking each item will have to parse through every item in the list defining the unwanted items. That said I still think it would be something cool to do.